# Select distinct first two octets using mssql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sample Data from my MS SQL table

```
Column Name: IPAddress
1.18.120.201,192.178.120.201
192.168.120.202,192.188.120.202,192.198.120.202
192.168.121.3
192.169.121.50
1.1.1.1
11.11.11.11
```

AS an output I want

```
192.168
192.169
192.178
192.188
192.198
1.18
1.1
11.11
```

The `IPAddress` column can have multiple ip address values as well.

I have written something like below. Please let me know what changes do i need to make in the query

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IPAddress))),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    ...
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IPAddress)))
```

Comment: Just modified the code checkt it once\

Comment: @mealhour Hey did you check the modified code

Answer (score 0):

Try this Below

```
 ;WITH cte(IPAddress)
AS
(
SELECT '1.18.120.201,192.178.120.201'                       UNION ALL
SELECT '192.168.120.202,192.188.120.202,192.198.120.202'    UNION ALL
SELECT '192.168.121.3'                                      UNION ALL
SELECT '192.169.121.50'                                     UNION ALL
SELECT '1.1.1.1'                                            UNION ALL
SELECT '11.11.11.11'                        
)
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 0, CHARINDEX('.', IPAddress, CHARINDEX('.', IPAddress) + 1)) AS IPAddress
FROM (
    SELECT  Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS IPAddress
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(IPAddress, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS IPAddress
        FROM cte
        ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY IPAddress.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
    ) DT
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Expected Result

```
IPAddress
---------
192.198
192.188
192.178
192.169
192.168
11.11
1.18
1.1
```

Comment: Your query is returning three octets for some IPs that have value such as `11.1.1.1' or  `1.1.1.1`

Comment: My code works according to your sample data and your expected result,how comes i know how data in your table

Comment: Add more sample data in the column with expected output

Comment: wait i will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t(IPAddress varchar(15))
insert into #t(IPAddress)
select '192.168.120.201'
union all select '192.178.120.201'
union all select '192.168.120.202'
union all select '192.188.120.202'
union all select '192.198.120.202'
union all select '192.168.121.3'
union all select '192.169.121.50'

select DIstinct parsename(IPAddress,4) +'.'+parsename(IPAddress,3)  from #t
```

Comment: why i need to create a table

Comment: It is just for reference. you can use query direct on your data table.

Answer (score 0):

I would use following solution:

```
SELECT  x.ID,  y.XmlCol.value('concat(i[1], ".", i[2])', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM (
    SELECT  ID, CONVERT(XML, '<root><ip><i>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(IP, ',', '</i></ip><ip><i>'), '.', '</i><i>') + '</i></ip></root>')  AS IPAsXML
    FROM    @SourceTable s
) x OUTER APPLY x.IPAsXML.nodes('root/ip') y(XmlCol)
```

Results:

[image]

**[Demo here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a29621f6e5a9c0d1d85f844d4a9864d5)**